# how to check if given file lies anywhere under given directory by command line in windows xp?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

So for example i need to check if file C:\windows\system32\whatever.dll lies in c:\windows. Is it possible in a manner like `if not exists ...`, but here `if %file% lies in %directory%` ?

edit: I know the path to the file I'm looking for. The problem boils down to comparing strings, that is checking if path to the directory is contained at the beginning in a path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like

```
if not exists %directory%\%file%
```

in this way you create a full file-pathname like "c:\myfolder\yourfolder\myfile.txt" and check for it's existence

***Update***
this should works (but it's not tested)

```
:: starting folder
set RootPath=c:\myfolder\yourfolder\

::check all subfolder
for /R "%RootPath%" %%d IN (.) DO ( 
    echo %%d

    :: check all file in each subfolder
    for %%f IN ("%%~d\*.*") DO (

        :: check if your file exist 
        IF "%%~nxf"=="filenameImLookingFor.txt" (
              echo Found file here "%%~f"
        )
    )
)
```

- **%%~nxf**  will expand to filname with extension, without the path
- the "~" make also sure that the expanded variable will never contain
  prefix/postfix doublequte, so that you can add your own without
  having unexpected double-doublequote (that will obviously mess things
  up)

Here is a list of useful syntax for FOR variables (from the help of the FOR command)

> You can now use the following optional syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
>
> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable for %I and expands to the
>                drive letter and path of the first one found.
> %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
> ```

Comment: Yes, but the file could be in subdirectory, way down the tree.

Comment: @rs82 - Do you know in which directory it should be, or do you want know if it's anywhere _under_ a specified directory?

Comment: Why not simply check it in the subfolder with `if exists %%~d\%file%`, instead of using the `for %%f IN ("%%~d\*.*") DO ...` ?

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is I know the path to the file, the only obstacle is how I compare strings and tell if one variable (that is the directory I want to check against) is at beginning of a path for the file. (Sorry, but my English is little twisted.)

Comment: @jeb you absolutely can :-) but this was an already written and functioning script... and this way you can have some added felxibility, depending on your need. And, in the ending, copy/paste is fast :-)